# Laravel Create Custom Middleware to check User Permissions via Routes

Tags: php, laravel

I'd like to create a Custom Middleware to check if my user is allowed to enter the classroom. The classroom related routes should be protected by the ClassRoom Middleware, to check the user permission before redirecting to the controllers.

This is the classroom route group:

```php
Route::group(['prefix' => 'classroom/{classroom_id}', 'namespace' => 'Classroom', 'as' => 'classroom.'], function(){
    Route::resource('dashboard', 'DashboardController')->only(['index', 'create', 'store']);
});
```

This is the code to check the permission:

```php
    $classroom = ClassRoom::findOrFail($classroom_id);

        $ok = false;
        foreach ($classroom->users as $classroom_user) {
          if ($classroom_user->id == user()->id) {
            $ok = true;
          }
        }

        if (!$ok) {
          return redirect()->route('user.classrooms.index');
        }
```

Comment: Have a look at policies: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authorization#authorizing-actions-using-policies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run command:

```
php artisan make:middleware CheckPermission
```

Your middleware:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class CheckPermission
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

       // apply your permission logic here

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

app/Http/Kernel.php

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    ... ,
    'check-permission' => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckPermission::class,
];
```

In route file (web.php)

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['check-permission'], 'prefix' => 'classroom/{classroom_id}', 'namespace' => 'Classroom', 'as' => 'classroom.'], function(){
    Route::resource('dashboard', 'DashboardController')->only(['index', 'create', 'store']);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To create middleware in laravel you use php artisan make:middleware YourCustomMiddleWare

You'll then need to register it in app/Http/Kernel.php in the protected routeMiddleware array

You add it to the route like a regular middleware

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/middleware